# Tooltip only shows when running from source

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

I have a [hierarchical flexgrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241752%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) control with the `ToolTipText` property set, and when I run from source the tooltip displays as it should. But when I compile it and run that way, the tooltip doesn't display.

I've tried to remove anything listening to `MouseMove` in the hopes that that would fix it, and when I add some code to put the tooltip text into a message box, it appears to be set correctly. Can anyone think of why this would be happening?

---

Update: It appears that the problem arises when I host the grid inside another user control. E.g.: make container.ctl, which is just a blank control but with ControlContainer = True. Then make gridholder.ctl, which is a mshfg inside of a container.ctl. Lastly, embed gridholder.ctl into some form. Tooltips on the flexgrid don't appear to show up.

I'm interested to see how reproducible this is...

Comment: It shows for me when I compile it. Try this for me. Create a new project. In a new form add just a grid and set a tool tip and directly compile it. Now test the EXE file. Does it work on this?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Yes a simple test program doesn't have this flaw. So there must be some other thing in my program causing this, but I have no idea what to look for.

Comment: How big is the program? Can you zip the form which has the grid and upload it at wikisend.com and then share the link here. I wouldn't mind having a look at it. :)

Comment: I wish I could, but it's huge and part of an even huger application. Thank you for your generous offer though.

Comment: ic :) Ok try this for me. Create a new form and then COPY the `grid` (without code) from your app to this new project and compile it. See if the tooltip now shows.

Comment: Interesting idea, but yes the tooltip works in the new project

Comment: Hmm. Few other things that you can try :) Backup your project. Then delete the grid and recreate it. Compile it and check. Does that make any difference? I am off to bed now. It is already quite late here LOL. But will have a look at it when I get up.

Comment: Does deleting all code from the form and see it that resolves the issue?

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the problem - can you see the update?

Comment: I can duplicate in the IDE. BUT, if you create a control that has the MSHFlexgrid in the control itself, it works fine.

Comment: Interestingly, using a picture box in the same manner (which is a container control) does not have that problem.

Comment: @SpectralGhost: I'm wondering if this a bug in the MSHFlexGrid control. Tooltips still work correctly if you create your own container control (like the OP) and put a **CommandButton** or other standard control inside of it. No extra code needed to make it work in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a workaround for this issue yet, but I have a better idea of why it's happening after some testing and stepping through some of the VB6 runtime code in WinDBG.

The first interesting thing is that VB6 doesn't use the standard tooltip display mechanisms provided by Windows. For example, it doesn't use **WM_NOTIFY** messages to show/hide tooltips, or any of the other "standard" tooltip support described in the [documentation explaining how tooltips work in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Instead, the VB6 runtime has its own way of managing and displaying tooltips. In principle, it's similar to in some ways to the standard Windows way of dealing with tooltips, but it's also different in a quite a few areas.

A breakdown of how VB6 does tooltips:

- When a VB6 program starts, the runtime uses [**SetWindowsHookEx**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to install a mouse hook for the program's main thread.
- The mouse hook intercepts all mouse messages sent to the program, in particular all **WM_MOUSEMOUSE** messages
- Whenever the mouse hook runs, it calls an internal method in the VB6 runtime to get the object pointer (HCTL) of the control that the mouse is currently over top of. Note that this is an actual COM interface pointer, not a window handle.
- It translates the HCTL to the corresponding window handle (HWND).
- It checks to see if the mouse position is within that window's rectangle.
- If so, it retrieves the **ToolTipText** property for the control. If this is not empty, it creates a tooltip window and displays the tooltip after a 700ms delay.

The problem with the MSHFlexGrid (and I imagine other controls that are not standard VB6 controls) is that this code doesn't retrieve the correct HCTL when you hover over the control and it's inside a custom container.

In that case, the code retrieves the HCTL of the custom container, not the HCTL of the MSHFlexGrid itself. Therefore, it retrieves the container's **ToolTipText** property (which is empty) and not the grid's **ToolTipText**, and therefore won't display a tooltip.

I'm not sure exactly *why* it does this, because as noted in the comments on your question, all of this works correctly if you use a **PictureBox** as your container.

I suspect the **PictureBox** has code to handle this correctly that is not included when you create your own container.

I'll update this answer with an actual workaround if I can find one. The only thing I can think right now is to somehow "sync" your container's **ToolTipText** property with the grid's **ToolTipText** property, so that when VB6 requests the container's **ToolTipText**, it will return the value of the grid's **ToolTextTip** property instead.

This is easier said than done, however, because **ToolTipText** is an extender property, and extender properties take precedence over properties that you write yourself that have the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do with this

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I found what I think is the underlying problem. Your user control is not implementing any method for the controls to interact with. User Controls that are Container Controls need to implement the Extender functionality. These two links are the best I've found on the subject so far.

http://www.justvb.net/obook/ch7.htm#UsingtheExtenderObject

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733622(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733622%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. I should make container.ctl an "Extender" object? How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to implement. Not something I've worked with. I'm curious so I plan to spend some time on it this weekend.